# How to make a new request with $http.get every 3 seconds and get data outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I want to get some data from this page http://orbit5.ds.cs.umu.se:8888/vrio/debug/blk. the data on this page updates every time you refresh the page. So I would like to have these updated values. In order to update the values I could use $timeout but then I need to somehow get these values outside of getdata because I want to then plug these values into another function for making a chart otherwise the whole chart will keep on rendering every time the function updates. and I cannot get the values outside of the function I found this answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) but most of the answers as far as I understand use data from inside the function.

How can I get the updated values outside of the JavaScript function and plug them into another function? Or maybe there is another better approach to solve this problem?

my code:

```
    function getData(){
  var data;

  $http.get(path).then(function(response){
    data = response.data
    console.log(response.data) //works fine
  })
  return data
}

console.log(data)//returns undefined
```

Now If I want to update the function with $timeout

I would need to do something like this

```
$timeout(getData, 3000)
```

now how can I get to these updated values?

Edit:

```
var  myData =  setInterval( function(){
   $http.get(path).then(function(response){
    return response.data['Block Devices']
  })
}, 1000 );

console.log(myData)
  });
```

returns 14 I dont know what that is but certainly not right data

Comment: You can't use data varialbe outside the function as scope of data variable is currently only inside the function. But, what you can do is, declare data variable outside the function rather than inside the function, then it will be in the global scope and then i guess it can be used outside the function.

Comment: tried that already it just then returns an empty array even if I try to push the values from inside the function to global variable

Answer (score 2):

Use $q of angular, you need to inject $q as dependency,

```
function getData(){

  var deffered = $q.defer();
  var data;
  $http.get(path).then(function(response){
    data = response.data
    $q.resolve(data);
  })
  return deffered.promise;
}

var getDataCall = getData();

getDataCall.then(function(data){
console.log(data);
})
```

if you want to repeat this call use, `$interval(fn, delay, [count], [invokeApply], [Pass]);`

see doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Try this for repeating, (i haven't tried),

```
function getData(){   
  var deffered = $q.defer();
  var data;
  $http.get(path).then(function(response){
    data = response.data
    $q.resolve(data);
  })
  return deffered.promise;
}


$interval(function(){
  getData().then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
  });
},3000);
```

Comment: This could be close but then how do I add $timeout or setinterval to this I need to make a new request to path every 3 seconds?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check

Answer (score 1):

You just need to run the code in an interval:

```
setInterval( function(){
    $http.get(path).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        // Update your page here
    });
}, 3000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Angular's `$interval` module to do this.

Essentially, you have a function called `getData` which uses the `$http` module. Then, in the resolution of that promise, you set the `$scope.chartData` with the new data.

You then call that function on an interval:

```
$interval($scope.getData, 3000); // every 3 seconds
```

You don't need `$q` if you do this in your controller, but you should probably take it out of the controller and put it in a service and then use the `$q` module.

[Here is a CodePen on HTTP polling in Angular](http://codepen.io/tinacious/pen/wMRoaE) with a full Angular app as the solution that works with your provided endpoint.

**Update**: If you wanted to call it from an external function outside of your controller, you can do that by creating a factory that uses `$q` and injecting that into your controller. The same example but with a factory: [CodePen on HTTP polling in Angular (using a factory)](http://codepen.io/tinacious/pen/adPBKW)

You'll also note the `$scope.getBytesWritten` method in the example with the factory/service. You need to execute a function in order to get part of the data—simply trying to access a property of the chart data won't update that single value. Please refer to the [CodePen on HTTP polling in Angular (using a factory)](http://codepen.io/tinacious/pen/adPBKW).

Comment: thankyou so much for your answer. just one more question suppose I want to plug chartData into another function in javascript how would I do that??

Comment: I've updated my answer to add an example that uses a factory/service. You can inject that service into your controller so that it can be reused.

Comment: Thank you. this is really very helpful, But what I still do not get is how can I get for example Bytes_Written and do something like this function createChart(){var data = Bytes_Written}

Comment: again many many thanks for your answer I am really going crazy trying to figure thsi out

Comment: I've updated my answer to refer to the updated example with the factory with a new method to get the bytes written.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,**

In AngularJS ,
 there is a service called **$timeout** , that does **exactly what you're looking for in one loop.**

Check the whole official documentation here : [$timeout service documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Answer (score 0):

### Using the `$interval` service with the `$http` service

The `$http` service returns a promise that you can use for **chaining**. Use the `$interval` service to repeditively create an new promise and **chain** from that promise to put the updated data on scope.

**Return** that promise and **chain** from it.

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("myVm",
  function($scope,$http,$interval) {
    var count = 0;

    function getHttpPromise(url) {
        var promise = $http.post(url);
        //return for chaining
        return promise;
    };

    function updateScope(promise) {
        //chain from promise
        promise.then (function (response) {
            count++;
            $scope.currentCount = "Current response "+count;
        });        
    };

    updateScope(getHttpPromise("/echo/json"));

    var intervalPromise =  $interval( function(){
        updateScope(getHttpPromise("/echo/json"));
    }, 1000 );

    $scope.onStopUpdate = function () {
        $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
    });
});
```

The above example has a function `getHttpPromise` that **returns** a promise for **chaining**. The `updateScope` function **chains** from the httpPromise to update the scope. The example then uses the `$interval` service to update the scope every 1000 milliseconds.

The `$interval` service also returns a promise that can be used for **chaining** and for cancellation.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1q578j4L/).