# Updating a table from mysql using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn angularjs and I seem to have trouble with making my table live.
I am fetching json from a php file, placing it in scope and using ng-repeat. 
I understand that to update the table I need to update the array in scope, but I have no clue of how to write it properly.

The html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in livedt | orderBy:tableOrder | filter:Search">
                    <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ x.ph }}</td>
                    <td>{{ x.ec }}</td>
                    <td>{{ x.tmp }}</td>
                    <td>{{ x.inpdate }}</td>
            </tr>
```

The controller:

```
app.controller('tableCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("livedata.php").then(function (response) {
        $scope.livedt = response.data;
    });
});
```

Comment: what happens when you run your code? on your actual page, do you have an actual "<table>" tag?

Comment: `console.log(response.data)` and check values exist in console.
Maybe remove `filter` and `orderBy` until you get it working.

Comment: When your page loads, hit Fn+F12 and look at the Console tab

Comment: The table and filters all work perfrctly fine, but I want to keep pulling new data from the php.

Comment: Look at -- [Using the `$interval` service with the `$http` service](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35325145/5535245).

Comment: Looks exactly like what I have been looking for!
Didn't notice that thread in first place, my bad.